# Appropriate SecureRandom method for API token for use in URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, secure-random

I am aware that SecureRandom (ruby on rails) offers multiple methods for generating tokens

Is there some method that is designed for urls?

e.g.

```
SecureRandom.hex(32)
```

```
SecureRandom.base64(20)
```

etc

The main reason I ask is to ensure I don't accidentally generate tokens with characters that are illegal in urls. Ultimately I need to generate tokens of the same length that are safe in urls

Answer (score 1):

```
SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
```

Documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-urlsafe_base64)